# How to make bullet hit target without an error in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I currently making a shooting game and when projectile hits target, game crashes exactly on this part:

```
for x in range(10):
    ship=canvas.create_image(470, 0, anchor=NW, image=warship)
    v=random.randint(1, 3)
    for y in range(300):
        canvas.move(ship, 0, v)
        canvas.move(cannonball, v1, 0)
        ball_locate=canvas.coords(cannonball)
        ship_locate=canvas.coords(ship)
        tk.update()
        sleep(0.02)
        if ball_locate[2]>=470 and ball_locate[1]<=ship_locate[3] and ball_locate[3]>=ship_locate[1]:
            po=canvas.create_image(ball_locate[1], 230, anchor=NW, image=kill)
            canvas.delete(ship)
            hit.play()
            b+=1
            ships_dead.config(text='''Neutralised
ships:''' + str(b))
            canvas.delete(cannonball)
            sleep(2)
            canvas.delete(po)
            break
```

The error and window of game.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Files are here: [Warship shooter](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SjXyDg8iiv8jW2JVSvqTjkuZ1av8Lvy-?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is the exact line that it is crashing on, and what is the exact error that you are receiving when the crash happens?

Comment: "List index out of range" means that the your index values are too big for the list.  You are using indexes of 1, 2, and 3 for ball_locate and ship_locate.  One of the lists is smaller than you think it is. Add this print before the if statement:  print(len(ball_locate), len(ship_locate)).  It will tell you how many items are in each list.

Comment: I looked up the details for canvas.coords(). When you are dealing with an image, it only returns a single (x,y) value: ship_locate[0] and ship_locate[1].  Update your question with the error and I will post this as an official answer.